# Input security with "(int)" in PHP?

Tags: php, security, int

Is `(int)$_POST['post_id']` really safe? Won't it allow negative integers?

Comment: I think we all have an idea about what you mean by "safe", but you may want to clarify safe *for what*.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Assuming you mean *safe* in terms of *SQL injection* or *XSS attacks*, then *probably* yes. Casting to an `int` only makes sure the value is an integer. An integer is not *usually* dangerous in any context. It does not guarantee the safety of the integer's *value* though. It may be `0`, which may or may not have a special meaning in your code, for example when comparing to `false`. Or it may be negative, which, again, may or may not have any side effects in your code.

"Safety" isn't an absolute thing. The string `"1 = 1; DROP TABLE users"` by itself is pretty *safe*, too. It just depends on the context you're using it in. Just the same, a `0` is perfectly safe until your code includes `if (!$number) deleteAllUsers();`.

Comment: that's most probably what the OP wanted to know.

Answer (score 3):

It is "safe", depending on what you want to do. It will only cast the variable to an integer as far as `PHP`s memory usage is concerned. It will allow negative integers.

Answer (score 3):

For (int) in PHP:

```
decimal     : [1-9][0-9]*
            | 0

hexadecimal : 0[xX][0-9a-fA-F]+

octal       : 0[0-7]+

binary      : 0b[01]+

integer     : [+-]?decimal
            | [+-]?hexadecimal
            | [+-]?octal
            | [+-]?binary
```

Never cast an unknown fraction to an integer, as this can sometimes lead to unexpected results.

Check out [the PHP documentation on integers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php).

Answer (score 1):

The use of `int` is for type <strike>hinting</strike> casting, like

```
php -r "var_dump( (int) '123d');"
>>> int(123)

php -r "var_dump( (int) '-123d');"
>>> int(-123)

php -r "var_dump( (int) '<script>alert(false)</script>');"
>>> int(0) (xss, no problem)
```

is safe for negative integers

my mistake: type hinting only applicable for array and object

[more details on type casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is "safe" in terms of SQL injection or XSS attacks.

In addition, if you utilize unsigned integers (no negative values) for primary keys or other fields in your database (save space) you need to use PHP function abs() and casting to prevent unhandled errors:

```
$safe_int = abs((int)$_POST['post_id']);
```

Comment: This question is almost a year old. Already answered and accepted. What's the point in digging it out?

Comment: I know, but this is improved answer so it is not important the time of original question agains security treads those days!

Comment: there is absolutely nothing security related